# Stop other processes from writing to tty

Tags: c, output, posix, tty

I am interested in stopping all processes other than the one I am writing from printing to the tty in which my process is running. It can be assumed that my application is only to be ran in a real tty.

I would prefer a POSIX compliant solution, but ubuntu or freeBSD specific solutions would be appreciated as well. The system I am coding on is Ubuntu 14.

I am writing in C, but portability is not so much of a concern that I would need to avoid system calls, nonstandard headers (like POSIX headers), etc.

I am having a hard time seeing where to start with this. I thought maybe stty would have a command for it, but I couldn't find one in its man page.

To illustrate my issue, my application uses the terminal as a character grid rather than a sequence of lines, so when a keyboard is plugged in, I get output regarding configuration, which overwrites the characters I have in place. I am about to resort to regular reprinting of the entire screen, but I'd really like to avoid that. So, to do that, I really need to stop other processes from writing to the tty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understood you correctly you need mutual exclusion for a TTY, right? Google for that if in doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the correct terminology. I am having trouble finding any relevant links. Do you have any ideas on some alternative ways to word my searches?

Comment: @KyleStewart As far as I know `printf` and Co for `stdio.h` are thread-safe

Comment: @Sergy Kanaev, Yes, that is my understanding as well, in that sub buffer sized writes are written atomically. However, my problems relate to things being written in between my calls to printf. So say I have a menu that displays an asterisk next to the highlighted option, then if something else is written it will wreck the text of my menu, even while I keep updating the asterisk location properly.

Comment: So, who are the other programs who are writing to the tty? Under which user are they running? Does `mesg n` work for your scenario? Are the messages coming from some syslog daemon running as root (and if so, can you configure that daemon to stop spewing output to the tty?)?

Comment: @ninjalj, It is not that these other writes are happening regularly, but they do happen and that makes my application buggy. I have only observed writes on connection/disconnection of a usb keyboard, but there are others I'd expect to be a problem (like for example, errors on dd reads). I could never identify every possible source, I need to either universally block other processes from writing to the tty, or else constantly refresh my screen. Like I said before, I really prefer the former.

Comment: May I ask, why is `dd`'s stdout and stderr not redirected elsewhere?

Comment: @ninjalj, I think what you said about 'mesg n' could work, but I've had some trouble recreating the writes I originally observed. I'll comment on how that goes later today. As for dd's stdout, stderr: I don't typically redirect them (as I understand it of=foo means that stdout stays the same but the copying doesn't use stdout). Is there some reason I should be redirecting them as a habit?